# NodeJS - Сервер сбрасывает соединение

Tags: node.js

Всем добрый день! Помогите пожалуйста, не могу управиться со следующей ошибкой, что выводит консоль:

```
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/
connected to server
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close


connection is closed

Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
    at Socket.writeAfterFIN [as write] (net.js:454:14)
    at ReadStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\cann\Desktop\Data\nodejs\3\hello.js:19:11)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)
    at ReadStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)
    at TTY.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
  code: 'EPIPE'
}
```

Код моей программы:

```
var http = require('http')
var net = require('net')
var client = new net.Socket()
client.setEncoding('utf-8')

// Создаём наш сервер
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
   res.end()
}).listen(8124)


// Подключение к серверу
client.connect ('8124','localhost', function () {
   console.log('connected to server');
   client.write('Who needs a browser to communicate?');
});
// Полученные данные отправляются серверу
process.stdin.on('data', function (data) {
   client.write(data);
});
// Возвращаемые данные выводятся на консоль
client.on('data',function(data) {
   console.log(data);
});
// При закрытии сервера
client.on('close', function() {
   console.log('connection is closed');
});

client.on('error', function (err) {
   console.error(err)
})

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/')
```

Comment: Вы создали HTTP-сервер, но посылаете в него не HTTP-запросы. Естественно он отвечает ошибкой.

Comment: @AlexeyTen А-а... Хм, действительно.

Comment: Во здесь есть решение этой задачи на сокетах: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346911/creating-a-tcp-socket-with-net-createconnectionport-host-in-node-js#answer-6348248